# Nucleic acid extractions

Tags: molecular-biology, lab-techniques, methods

Is it fine to leave pulverized plant tissue in CTAB buffer at -80 degrees over night? will the buffer remain effective to generate good quality nucleic acids?

Comment: Someone push back but freeze-dried or frozen in liquid N2 is shown to be preferable, typically.